# Python: Add rows with different column names to dict/dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to add data (dictionaries) to a dictionary, where every added dictionary represent a new row. It is a iterative process and it is not known what column names a new added dictionary(row) could have. In the end I want a pandas dataframe. Furthermore I have to write the dataframe every 1500 rows to a file ( which is a problem, because after 1500 rows, it could of course happen that new data is added which has columns that are not present in the already written 1500 rows to the file).

I need a approach which is very fast (maybe 26ms per row). My approach is slow, because it has to check every data if it has new column names and in the end it has to reread the file, to create a new file where all columns have the same lengths. The data comes from a queue which is processed in another process.

```
import pandas as pd
def writingData(exportFullName='path', buffer=1500, maxFiles=150000, writingQueue):
    imagePassed = 0
    with open(exportFullName, 'a') as f:
        columnNamesAllList = []
        columnNamesAllSet = set()
        dfTempAll = pd.DataFrame(index=range(buffer), columns=columnNamesAllList)
        columnNamesUpdated = False
        for data in iter(writingQueue.get, "STOP"):
            print(imagesPassed)
            dfTemp = pd.DataFrame([data],index=[imagesPassed])
            if set(dfTemp).difference(columnNamesAllSet):
                columnNamesAllSet.update(set(dfTemp))
                columnNamesAllList.extend(list(dfTemp))
                columnNamesUpdated = True
            else:
                columnNamesUpdated = False
            if columnNamesUpdated:
                print('Updated')
                dfTempAll = dfTemp.combine_first(dfTempAll)
            else:
                dfTempAll.iloc[imagesPassed - 1] = dfTemp.iloc[0]

            imagesPassed += 1

            if imagesPassed == buffer:
                dfTempAll.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
                dfTempAll.to_csv(f, sep='\t', header=True)
                dfTempAll = pd.DataFrame(index=range(buffer), columns=columnNamesAllList)  
                imagePassed = 0
```

Reading it in again:

```
    dfTempAll = pd.DataFrame( index=range(maxFiles), columns=columnNamesAllList)
    for number, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(exportFullName, delimiter='\t', chunksize=buffer, low_memory=True, memory_map=True,engine='c')):
        dfTempAll.iloc[number*buffer:(number+1*buffer)] = pd.concat([chunk, columnNamesAllList]).values#.to_csv(f, sep='\t', header=False)  # , chunksize=buffer
        #dfTempAll = pd.concat([chunk, dfTempAll])
    dfTempAll.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True).to_csv(exportFullName, sep='\t', header=True)
```

**Small example with dataframes**

So to make it clear. Lets say I have a 4 row already existent dataframe (in the real case it could have 150000 rows like in the code above), where 2 rows are already filled with data and I add a new row it could look like this with the exception that the new data is a dictionary in the raw input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4),columns=['A','B','D'], data={'A': [1, 2, 'NaN', 'NaN'], 'B': [3, 4,'NaN', 'NaN'],'D': [3, 4,'NaN', 'NaN']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[2],columns=['A','C','B'], data={'A': [0], 'B': [0],'C': [0] })#
```